# Proof in Intuitionistic logic: $\neg \neg A \to \neg \neg B \vdash \neg \neg (A \to B)$

Tags: logic

I have a problem with proving the below sequent in intuitionistic logic:
$$
\neg \neg A \to \neg \neg B \vdash \neg \neg (A \to B)
$$
I stuck here:
[image: proof]

What should I put in $6th$ line? Is my approach even correct?
I noticed that Generally, I have problems with proving sequents with double negation in intuitionistic logic. Is there any pattern for solving such examples?

Comment: You _should_ be having trouble, because it's not provable.

Comment: @ZhenLin Why is that? I was asked to solve that on the exam last week. If you are correct that would mean this exercise doesn't make sense...

Comment: There are some variants that are provable: for example, $(A \to B) \vdash (\lnot \lnot A \to \lnot \lnot B)$, or $(\lnot \lnot A \to B) \vdash (A \to B)$. But the one you are asking about is not. Take $A = \top$; then it simplifies to $\lnot \lnot B \vdash B$, which is an intuitionistic taboo.

Comment: @ZhenLin I'm sorry, I made a mistake in the title and description... It should be  $\neg \neg A \to \neg \neg B \vdash \neg \neg (A \to B)$

Comment: @damian9E Welcome to Math Stackexchange! The answer to your question can be found in the linked duplicate - more specifically, see the second proof in user Z.A.K.'s answer there.

Comment: Modifying your proof:$$\tiny\def\ftch#1#2{~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\ftch{~~1.~\lnot\lnot A\to\lnot\lnot B}{\ftch{~~2.~\lnot(A\to B)}{\ftch{~~3.~A}{~~4.~\lnot\lnot A\quad\lnot\lnot\textsf{i (3)}\\~~5.~\lnot\lnot B\quad{\to}\textsf{e (1,4)}\\\ftch{~~6.~B}{\ftch{~~7.~A}{~~8.~B\quad\textsf{reit (6)}}\\~~9.~A\to B\quad{\to}\textsf{i (7-8)}\\10.~\bot\quad\lnot\textsf{e (9,2)}}\\11.~\lnot B\quad\lnot\textsf{i (6-10)}\\12.~\bot\quad\lnot\textsf{e (11,5)}\\13.~B\quad\bot\textsf{e (12)}}\\14.~A\to B\quad{\to}\textsf{i (3-13)}}\\15~.\lnot\lnot (A\to B)\quad\lnot\textsf{i (2-14)}}$$

Comment: ... Of couse there should be a $\bot$ derived between 14 and 15.